# Why is didUpdatePushCredentials never called

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm trying to get push notifications to my iOS app using PushKit, but I never get a callback when registering for the notifications.

I actually DID both register ok and received notification earlier, but I must have managed to screw something up or gotten blacklisted by Apple.

I can still send the notifications fine (to sandbox apps), but I never get the notifications and I assume this has to do with the missing callback when registering in the app. Sending to production renders an "INVALID TOKEN" error which I assume is fine as the app isn't in the app store.

Any ideas on what's going on here ? Please ask for more info if I missed something.

[gist with AppDelegate/settings/console output](https://gist.github.com/nmodin/9e00e61b82d6b1446ddd)

Comment: I think your push kit registry object is being deallocated since its a local variable. Make it as an instance variable of UIApplication and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. As @sugarngp mentioned in his comment above, my issue is that my PKPushRegistry object was getting deallocated. Once I made it an instance variable of my AppDelegate it fixed the issue.